# Delete with inner join takes more than 40 seconds to delete 500 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I have this request :

```
delete L 
from L
inner join M on L.id = M.ref_id 
             or L.id = M.news_id
```

And it takes between 39 and 50 seconds to finish to delete 588 rows.

Select is very fast 0,015 sec if in my query I replace `delete L from L` by `select * from L`

Here is [my trace in xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VXZgMUvuQfRAEjfHhcBx-p4iy15aUTKX)

and here is [my explain plan file .SQLPlan](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XtOZYXq4UNJeVVuYNY2E4jRRyB-B15sL)

Hope you can help what im missing here, what is the problem here ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189913/discussion-on-question-by-bee-delete-with-inner-join-takes-more-than-40-seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Delete rows from a large clustered table is usually slow.

The famous "BETWEEN" discussed in the comments, is a partition from the clustered index, it takes the min and max values from your join. That's why is recommended to delete in batches.

> I guess there could be few general recommendations but it always
>   depend upon different things like the amount of data, hardware,
>   memory, log file size etc. - Delete rows in batches. The optimal batch
>   size would depend upon the environment but generally its around 10K to
>   100K. - Delete in the order of the clustered index - If possible turn
>   your recovery model to BULK/SIMPLE for minimal logging. - If possible
>   drop constraints like foreign key constraint from the child table. -
>   If possible disable non-clustered indexes - Depending upon the amount
>   of data you are going to delete, may be it would be better to export
>   the data to a new table and then drop the old table OR keep it with a
>   different name for future reference. As you can see, mainly it would
>   depend upon the situation and environment.

This is the best answer, "maybe you need to Tune the system, not the query"

> But from a delete statement, I would prefer to see most of the cost
>   coming from the delete itself. Understand, a clustered index is where
>   the data is stored in a table that has a clustered index. When you
>   delete, you're deleting from the cluster. That's not to say that you
>   might not be able to tune this further, but you're seeing very normal,
>   even desirable behavior. Without seeing exactly what you're doing,
>   it's hard to make suggestions, but it could be that you're doing it
>   all right. In which case, maybe you need to tune the system, not the
>   query. Get faster disks. Make sure you're not under memory pressure.
>   Check your wait statistics to see where most of the work is being done
>   on the server and make adjustments from there.

If you can not do any of those things, probably will be faster to use a loop to delete row by row....

source: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/90223/how-to-reduce-the-cost-of-clustered-index-delete.html

Answer (score -1):

If it's truly slow because of the join, and not because the delete itself is slow, I've found it useful to trick SQL into generating a more optimized query by calculating intermediate results into a table variable, and then working off that table variable.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    id int
);

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT id
from L
inner join M on L.id = M.ref_id 
         or L.id = M.news_id;

DELETE FROM L WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM @temp)
```

Comment: @bee have you try those : 
DELETE FROM L WHERE ID IN (SELECT ref_id FROM M) OR ID IN (SELECT news_id FROM M)

And try to add 3 index id , news_id, ref_id

Comment: IN () clause is bad way to achieve this (ps: same or worst result)

Comment: This is worse than the original - a JOIN is still performed but now, the optimizer has *no* indexes or statistics to use in order to optimize the DELETE.

Comment: @pascalsanchez I only suggested it because occasionally I have run into situations where SQL Server makes really bad decisions based on its statistics, and after many many attempts to fix it, the only way I could get rid of those bad optimizations was to break the query into parts using table variables so the optimizer doesn't do something stupid.  Usually in those situations, the queries are super complex, but I thought it might be worth trying here.